# How would you provide return within X seconds semantics for a servlet request?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, jms

My client wants my servlet to be able to return results within X seconds if there is something to return, else return zt X seconds with a message like "sorry could not return within specified time"

This is really a synchronos call to a servlet with a timeout. Is there an established pattern for this sort of behavior ?

What would be the ideal way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

The request handler thread creates a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) called myQueue and gives it to a worker thread which will place its result in the queue when it is finished.  Then the handler thread calls "`myQueue.poll(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`" and returns the serialized result if it gets one or your "timeout" error if it gets null instead (meaning the "poll" call timed out).  Here is an example of how it might look:

```
// Servlet handler method.
BlockingQueue<MyResponse> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MyResponse>();
Thread worker = new Thread(new MyResponseGenerator(queue));
worker.start();
MyResponse response = queue.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (response == null) {
  worker.interrupt();
  // Send "timeout" message.
} else {
  // Send serialized response.
}
```

Note that thread management in general (but especially in a servlet container) is full of pitfalls, so you should become very familiar with the servlet specification and behavior of your particular servlet container before using this pattern in a production system.

Using a ThreadPool is another option to consider but will add another layer of complexity.

Comment: In addition to making sure to try and stop threads that exceed the timeout, you should also consider using a thread pool for the workers. You need to make sure you can control the upper bound for the number of threads that are created in your web app. If you don't clean up threads, and don't use a thread pool, you could get yourself a big pile of threads all contending with each other and slowing the whole mess down.

Comment: @rfeak, this is in a servlet container, am I allowed to create threadpools ?

Comment: @maerics, how would I create a worker thread ? this is a servlet container or an appserver that this servlet is running in.

Comment: @mafalda: unfortunately, managing threads is a no-no in servlet containers, so you should probably start reading up on J2EE (ugh).  But if you're just toying around (NOT running a production system) you could create a threadpool in your servlet init function using [Executors.newFixedThreadPool()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).

Comment: actually I was referring to your suggestion to create a thread or did you mean something else! I quote "creates a BlockingQueue52 called myQueue and gives it to a worker thread " - how to do that ?  Looks like you were responding to a non servlet container case... I mentioned servlets in my initial question

Comment: Sorry, I jumped ahead to the ThreadPool idea, please see the updated answer.

Comment: @maerics, Is there another way of doing this ? As you say, this is a frowned upon practice- starting threads in the servlet. Are there options in servlet containers where I can pass off a runnable to some entity that executes it and returns results... I would google but I dont know what to look for specifically.